Kubuntu 22.04 does not start
Good morning,
For unknown reason my Kubuntu 22.04 no longer starts (after 6 months of trouble-free operation).
This is what appears on the screen:

a keyboard
a connection window which has nothing to do with the usual window and with which it is impossible to connect

Thank you for your ideas


